# Tengo un botón aspx y tengo una función JavaScript , lo que quiero es que cuando se de click al botón en el back del botón me llame la función de el J

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
protected void AgregarCarrito_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ValorId = IdProducto;
}
```

Quiero llamar al JS:

```
function AgregarCarrito(IdProducto) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Productos.aspx/Listar",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ IdProducto: IdProducto }),
        success: function (data) {
            var Producto = JSON.parse(data.d);

            var producto = {
                IdProducto: IdProducto,
                Imagen: Producto[0]["ImagenPrincipal"],
                Nombre: Producto[0]["NombreProducto"],
                Descripcion: Producto[0]["Descripcion"],
                Precio: Producto[0]["Precio"],
                Cantidad: 1
            };

            var carritoActual = obtenerCarritoDelLocalStorage();
            var productoExistenteIndex = carritoActual.findIndex(function (item) {
                return item.IdProducto === producto.IdProducto;
            });

            if (productoExistenteIndex !== -1) {
                // El producto ya existe en el carrito, aumentar la cantidad
                carritoActual[productoExistenteIndex].Cantidad++;
            } else {
                // El producto no existe en el carrito, agregarlo
                carritoActual.push(producto);
            }

            guardarCarritoEnLocalStorage(carritoActual);

            cargarCarrito(); // Actualizar el carrito en la página
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Manejar cualquier error que ocurra durante la llamada AJAX
            console.error(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No entiendo tienes un evento que básicamente no hace nada y quieres que llame al script. Entonces, por lo que veo quieres enviar una petición al servidor que te retorna el llamado a un JS (con una id?), esta ultima vuelve a realizar un solicitud al servidor....porque no mejor que al presionar el botón se ejecute el ajax y ya ??

Comment: Concuerdo con Yussef, en este caso lo que estás haciendo es irte al servidor para que el servidor llame una función del lado del cliente, no posee mucho sentido, puedes llamar directamente la función AgregarCarrito sin necesidad de irte al servidor.